# Managing SQLite Database for Windows Store Apps using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am using SQLite database for my Windows Store app. I completed my requirement of usage of Database with the help of MSFT samples & Blogs. Now I want to Change/Update the Data which is in the Database File..

My Insert code like this..

```
                   using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
                    {
                        db.Insert(new ItemEpub.EpubBookList()
                        {
                            BookName = file.DisplayName,
                            BookPath = file.Path,
                        }
                        );
                        db.Commit();
                        db.Dispose();
                        db.Close();
                    }
```

I didn't get the Syntax & any simple information about Update the Database table.
Right now my code is:

```
    StorageFile DataFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Epub.db3");
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
        {
            db.Update EpubBookList Set
            string sql = UPDATE EpubBookList SET LastVisitedPage = '" + lastVisistedPageIndex + "',";
            db.Dispose();
            db.Close();
        }
```

May be this code looks like ugly, Apart from this code give me any Suggestion on Update the Exiting row in metro apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the existing record, first you need to get that object via SQL query [`Query<T>(...)`] or `Get<T>(...)` method. Then update the object properties and call `Update(...)` method.

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
{
        var objPerson = db.Query<Person>("select * from dbPerson where PersonId = ?", 9);

        /*** or ***/

        var objPerson = db.Get<Person>(9); // Here 9 is primary key value

        /*** update the object ***/

        objPerson.FirstName = "Matt";
        db.Update(objPerson);
}
```

You don't need to call `db.Dispose();` & `db.Close();` because you are using `using`.

Comment: Thanks you. It determines clearly for me. Can you post the relevant web link of blog or page which describes Advanced SQLite concepts. which are more about CURD operations & using Keys in database, I am some what new to DB.
  
I already go through Some samples of MSFT.

Comment: There's no sample I think in my mind. Better you post here if you are facing any issue.

Comment: Nope, no need of sample,.. & Right now I don't have any issues with what I did. I want to know any Blog that you know about Advanced Sqlite.
even I didn't get syntaxs for **Update, delete & select commends** with conditions